# less not displaying coloured output in konsole

Tags: command-line, bash, less

I know that the -r or -R switch on the less command is used to show coloured output, but it only seems to work with the --color=always flag on the command that is generating the output, but not all commands support this option.

E.g.
`apt search okular` returns a nice coloured output.
`apt search okular | less -R` returns monochrome output.

So, how do I get the coloured output when using less, just like I would without it?

Comment: That's because many commands suppress coloing of output when output is not to a terminal (e.g., it's redirected to a file, or piped to something else). Often commands also have options to override that behaviour. I don't know if `apt` has such an option, though. The problem isn't with `less` or konsole, but with `apt`. You could pipe to `cat` and the effect would the the same.

Comment: Thanks. After a search, `unbuffer` works around this "suppression". Ugh, I miss the simpler days.

Answer (score 1):

`unbuffer apt search okular | less -R` returns a coloured output in less.